# CodeIgniter constant from hook in library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hooks

There is a problem. Using the CodeIgniter 3, i have a hook that is loaded in 'pre_controller' points and initializes language constant - SITELANG:

```
define('SITELANG', $lang);
```

How do i can access to this constant in the CodeIgniter library constructor?

Comment: As I think what you want to achive, would be better to skip pre_controllers, and extend CI Controller, where you can access such variables. If you want a variable available in every controller, let me know, i can suggest. But currently, that wasn't your question :)

Comment: PHP constant is accessible just with calling it. 
Your problem is that you can't be sure when it will be loaded and when not

Comment: `var_dump(SITELANG);` in library constructor. Load that library in controller constructor and tell if it is output.

Answer (score 0):

In project i use MVC and HMVC both.
Solved the problem: load library in the constructor controller, not in autoload.php.
Thank everyone, especially @Tpojka.